# Using the Facebook pop OS X framework embedded in another OS X framework

Tags: macos, swift, frameworks, facebook-pop

Here’s what I’m trying to do, in a Mac App:

1. Mac App uses my own custom OS X framework called `Proto` (for short).
2. `Proto` has a class like `Animator.swift` that uses Facebook’s `pop` library. It uses symbols from it like `kPOPLayerBackgroundColor`.
3. `pop` provides frameworks for iOS and OS X. I’m only interested in the OS X version.

But I can’t seem to make this setup work. My Mac app can successfully use `Proto` up until I start trying to have `Proto` include (link to) the `pop.framework`. I can’t use Cocoapods for this project.

I feel like I’ve tried everything (bridging headers, frameworks, module maps, header paths, etc) but I can’t seem to get all the pieces right. Can someone give me a play by play on how to get this all to work correctly?

**Edit**

The errors vary, but the main problem seems to be I can’t get `Proto` code to find symbols from `pop`.

So, I’ve tried making a bridging header and doing `#import <pop/POP.h>` but then Swift gives me an error I can’t use bridging headers in a framework (although I’m staring at another framework that *does* use a bridging header :).

So I’ve tried instead importing pop in my framework’s umbrella header (`Proto.h`) but it still won’t compile, saying I `can’t import non-modular includes` (even though `pop-osx-framework.framework` says it **is** a module).

Comment: Any reason why this is being downvoted? Any suggestion you can make to improve this question would be nice!

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

What's the actual error or problem?  Generally you should be able to link your framework against their library and then use your framework in your app.  Is pop a library or an actual dynamic framework?  You should not link pop into the app likely, just into Proto.

Comment: Pop vends a dynamic library (framework) for OS X but I’m not convinced it’s properly configured. I can’t seem to bridge pop’s headers into Proto, so Proto code can’t find pop symbols.